# Calculated dates between two dates and modify them to the Range

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, dax

I have a peculiar requirement where we have start and end dates for a Report. So, when the user selects the start and end dates in the report, they should be able to retrieve all the records if it either falls under start date or end date and correct the dates accordingly later. I would need this accomplished in a **DAX Query**.

Below is just an example of how the Dataset looks like:

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [#Promos]
([ProductNumber]       INT, 
 [StartDate]           DATE, 
 [EndDate]             DATE, 
 [PromoCode]           VARCHAR(6), 
 [DaysAvailableInWeek] VARCHAR(20)
);
```

**DML:**

```
INSERT INTO [#Promos] ([ProductNumber], [StartDate], [EndDate], [PromoCode], [DaysAvailableInWeek])
VALUES (6512, '2020-01-11', '2020-01-13', 'ABC123', '1, 3, 5');
INSERT INTO [#Promos] ([ProductNumber], [StartDate], [EndDate], [PromoCode], [DaysAvailableInWeek])
VALUES(6514, '2020-01-12', '2020-01-14', 'ABC123', '4, 6');
INSERT INTO [#Promos] ([ProductNumber], [StartDate], [EndDate], [PromoCode], [DaysAvailableInWeek])
VALUES(2341, '2020-01-11', '2020-01-25', '321XYZ', '1, 2');
```

**Example-1:**

```
    SELECT *
    FROM #Promos 
    WHERE [StartDate] = '2020-01-12' 
    AND [EndDate] = '2020-01-14'
    ORDER BY 1;
```

The Expected output for the above query should be:

> ```
> ProductNumber StartDate   EndDate     PromoCode   DaysAvailableInWeek
> 2341          2020-01-12  2020-01-14  ABC123      1, 2
> 6512          2020-01-12  2020-01-13  ABC123      1, 3, 5
> 6514          2020-01-12  2020-01-14  ABC123      4, 6
> ```

**Example-2:**

```
SELECT *
FROM #Promos 
WHERE [StartDate] = '2020-01-11' 
AND [EndDate] = '2020-01-13'
ORDER BY 1;
```

The Expected output for the above query should be:

> ```
> ProductNumber StartDate   EndDate     PromoCode   DaysAvailableInWeek
> 2341          2020-01-11  2020-01-13  ABC123      1, 2
> 6512          2020-01-11  2020-01-13  ABC123      1, 3, 5
> 6514          2020-01-12  2020-01-13  ABC123      4, 6
> ```

**Example-3:**

```
SELECT *
FROM [#Promos] 
WHERE [StartDate] = '2020-01-11' 
AND [EndDate] = '2020-01-12'
ORDER BY 1;
```

The Expected output for the above query should be:

> ```
> ProductNumber StartDate   EndDate     PromoCode   DaysAvailableInWeek
> 2341          2020-01-11  2020-01-12  ABC123      1, 2
> 6512          2020-01-11  2020-01-12  ABC123      1, 3, 5
> 6514          2020-01-12  2020-01-12  ABC123      4, 6
> ```

What I tried so far with SQL:

```
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-12';
SET @EndDate   = '2020-01-14';

    SELECT [ProductNumber],
       CASE
           WHEN @StartDate BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate] THEN @StartDate
           WHEN @StartDate < [StartDate] THEN [StartDate]
       END AS [StartDate],
       CASE
           WHEN @EndDate BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate] THEN @EndDate
           WHEN @EndDate > [EndDate] THEN [EndDate]
       END AS [EndDate], 
       [PromoCode], 
       [DaysAvailableInWeek]
FROM [#Promos]
WHERE [StartDate] <= @EndDate
  AND [EndDate]   >= @StartDate
ORDER BY 1;
```

But, I would need something with DAX. Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to pass the selected dates in dax back to the sql query? Or import all the data then filter it?

Comment: Hi Jonee, I've already imported all data into Dataset and trying to compute the dates based on the filters.

Comment: Have you tried adding start date and end date as slicers, you can then select the date range you want to show the selected data?

Comment: The data is already sliced. If you see my examples, the Start or End Dates should be automatically "corrected" based on the date range passed.